# Auto Populate TextBoxes of Entity Form In MS CRM 2011 on basis of lookup field using jscript

Tags: textbox, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup, populate

I want to auto populate the text boxes on basis of lookup field result in an entity form

There are two entities

- **Account Holder**  with fields (Name,Address,**account number -primary key**, etc etc)
- **Expense claim**  with  fields (Name,Address,**Account number - lookup**, expenses etc etc)

Now I want that in selecting account number through a lookup the name, address these fields should get populated themselves.

Please help me by providing the exact jscript code to attain the desired.

Comment: Please note that questions which simply ask for someone to provide your code for you are not likely to be well received. Please tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**In brief:**
On Form load event, you can asynchronously retrieve parent's record by using **OData endpoint** and **jQuery** then parse the retrieved record and set your desired text fields.

Check this question, it will give you the right path 
[Dynamics CRM 2011 form jscript to retrieve lookup data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093409/dynamics-crm-2011-form-jscript-to-retrieve-lookup-data)